# Microsoft Graph Api ROPC - AADSTS65001

Tags: oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, azure-authentication

I have asp.net core web api which is talking to MS Garaph Api.I have Implemented [ROPC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) using service account to talk to onedrive. I have created the MS graph Api app in [MS](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/) Portal 2 years back using the same service account. The the portal is obsolete  now and the App is moved to Azure Portal. But i can get the Bearer token using ROPC and consuming Graph api and its working good.

Now i tried to mimic the same, i have created a new app in azure portal with same credentials and similar Metadata.The service account user type is member in azure Portal. I am getting the following error for the new App

**"error": "invalid_grant",
"error_description": "AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID**

any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance
Subbiah K

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to be the administrator of the tenant (if you are not a tenant administrator, you cannot give the administrator permission), you can set up user roles according to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-users-assign-role-azure-portal) process.

Then follow this process to grant administrator consent to the app:

1.Log in to https://portal.azure.com as a tenant administrator.

2.Open the registration of your application in the following location.

3.Go to settings and then the required permissions.

4.Press the grant permission button.

In the Azure portal, I registered the application for testing and used `User.Read` permission to demonstrate:

[image]
Then use the [ROPC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth-ropc) flow in postman to get the access token:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, I will try this. But i have an existing app without this admin Consent which is working good. I have compare the metadata which is identical to the working app.

Comment: @user3141198  If you need to grant certain permissions to the application, the administrator must consent.